# Other web applications in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I started to learn Django, and I have downloaded some videos from youtube and downloaded some free Django books. I feel that we can only develop blogs in Django. In every video or book explaining the framework, it is about making a blog.

Please correct me if we could develop another web application like a Tracking System, HR system, finance systems or sales application.

Comment: Yes, you can. Just have a look at [djangosites](https://www.djangosites.org/) for examples of sites built with django.

Comment: The only reason the blog is the main example in all books and tutorials. Is because it's a simple way to explain you lots of the basics in Django. But you can build a lot of different stuff with that awesome framework.

Comment: Thank you , could you please share a link which explain another Project example not a blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find couple of example which are not BLOG examples.

http://lightbird.net/dbe2/

you can find there: calendarapp, tracking_issues app.

shop:

https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/setting-complete-django-e-commerce-store-30-minutes

here you can find few good examples:

https://codingforentrepreneurs.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely build things that not blogs in Django. Blogs are used as example projects because they are fairly straightforward to design and understand, but you can build pretty much anything in Django as long as its a restful web service.

Comment: Do you know a link which explain other Project not a blog Thanks

Comment: @JonasDavid https://www.udemy.com/create-your-first-django-website-fast-free/  (it is no longer free, though not very expensive)